# Ukulele strumming pattern and meaning of chords in square brackets and normal brackets (using Lemon Tree as example)

Tags: notation, ukulele, strumming

Hi I'm new to playing ukulele (and never studied any music theory) and I'm trying to learn to play along [this arrangement of Lemon Tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NOeJw0spS0).

The Intro goes like
Am Em Am Em Dm Em Am [Em] (Am)

As far as I can figure out the strumming pattern is D D U U D U.

1st question here is what is [Em] in square brackets, and how to play it?
Just by playing it slowly and listening it seems [Em] is just plucking 3rd string followed by strumming all 3? Or is it plucking all 3? Also it seems like she actually plays 3 notes (regardless how many strings per note) so there's possibly one note I'm not able to figure out.

2nd question here is what is (Am) in regular brackets, and how to play it?
Just by listening it seems like it's just one down strum of Am.

Then for the chorus, I'm completely lost about how to play the sequence right about when she sings "just a yellow lemon tree" [at 1:17](https://youtu.be/7NOeJw0spS0?t=77), which sounds like the same strumming pattern for the G G7 (at the second instance of "lemon tree") - both sound like a quick alternation (that I can't figure out...)

Then at the Bridge at [2:14](https://youtu.be/7NOeJw0spS0?t=134), the strumming pattern also sounds different and I can't figure it out.

I suspect there are probably some standard techniques or strumming patterns followed here. Please enlighten me thank you.

Comment: This is not any kind of standard notation. Perhaps the arranger meant to indicate that the chords are optional, or emphasize they are strummed only once. Questions requesting transcribing recordings are off-topic.

Comment: Not the best tutorial. The strumming itself is pretty amateur, and the way it's explained is not clear, particularly for the beginner likely to try this out. Beginner key is poorly chosen too, with hardly beginner chords. Find a better version.